# How can I remove 'records per page' label text from datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Is there a way to remove the label "Records per page" from jQuery datatables? `"oLanguage": { "sSearch": "" }` Can be used to remove the search label, but is there something similar for the results per page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Use

```
"oLanguage": {"sLengthMenu": "\_MENU_"}
```

This worked for me.